# Why is my URL rewriting not working correctly?

Tags: nginx, url-rewriting

In order to use AMP templates, I'll append `/amp`for each concerned URL. For example `site.com/contact/amp`

I came up with this rule `rewrite "^/(.*)/?amp$" /$1?amp=1 break;` but it works perfectly only for the home page. if I enter `site.com/contact/amp` it redirects to `site.com/contact?amp=1`

so I have to use 2 rules:

`rewrite ^/(.*)/amp$ /$1?amp=1 break;
rewrite ^/amp$ /$1?amp=1 break;`

the first one for other pages and second for the homepage

Do you have any idea how I can achieve this with only 1 rule?

Thanks

Comment: Try: `^(/.+)?/amp$`

Comment: Hi @RichardSmith and thanks for your fast reply. I did try `rewrite ^(/.+)?/amp$ /$1?amp=1 break` seems to be working but partially: No 404 error but it does't return the value `$_GET['amp'] = 1`, am I missing something?

Comment: You should probably use: `$1/?amp=1`

Comment: still not working :/ `rewrite ^(/.+)?/amp$ $1/?amp=1 break;` redirects `site.com/contact/amp` to `site.com/contact?amp=1`. The home page works fine

Comment: Hi @RichardSmith, any idea how to solve this??

Comment: I'm facing the same issue, did you manage to solve it? @RichardSmith, do you have any suggestion for this? :)